# How to download sbt plugin source jars in a common sbt project?

Tags: scala, sbt

It's nature to download the dependencies source jars in a sbt project, using `sbt gen-idea` or idea's autoimport feature

but how can I download the sbt plugin source jars which I declared in `project/plugins.sbt`

Answer (score 7):

**IDEA**

IDEA *should* already do this*.

When you import a project and have `Download sbt sources` checked in **Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > sbt** then it will run the `updateSbtClassifiers` sbt task.

* Read the **Troubleshooting** section as there are several known issues with this.

---

**sbt**

As mentioned above, you can run the following sbt task:

```
sbt> updateSbtClassifiers
```

This command is somewhat special in that it knows to resolve the classifiers for the plugins. It also uses settings that are scoped to that task. See the caveat about [sbt/sbt#3432](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3432).

---

**Longer way**

It is important to understand that [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive).

Dependencies declared in `build.sbt` will be for the **proper build**.

Dependencies declared in `project/plugins.sbt` will be for the **meta-build**.

When you just run `updateSbtClassifiers` it is running this on the proper build, however the dependencies are actually for the meta-build. That is why I said that this task is a little special.

Another way (which can achieve different results) is to run the `updateClassifiers` task directly on the meta-build.

First switch over to the meta-build:

```
sbt> reload plugins
```

Now that you are in the meta-build run:

```
sbt:project> updateClassifiers
```

This will retrieve the `src` and `doc` for your dependencies (it may not actually do this for some plugins). Run `libraryDependencies` to see the dependencies of the meta-build.

To get back to the proper

```
sbt:project> reload return
```

For a handy all in one command run:

```
sbt> updateClassifiers;updateSbtClassifiers;reload plugins;updateClassifiers;updateSbtClassifiers;reload return
```

---

**Troubleshooting**

**Download failed**

You may see in the sbt logs that it failed to download either the `src` or `doc`. For example:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: rocks.muki#sbt-graphql;0.5.0!sbt-graphql.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: rocks.muki#sbt-graphql;0.5.0!sbt-graphql.jar(src)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

If you look just above you will see all the resolvers that it tried. You should see one for `sbt-plugin-releases` which is where most sbt plugins are published to. See [predefined resolvers](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html#Predefined) for more details.

If you do not see that it tried `sbt-plugin-releases` then chances are you have encountered [sbt/sbt#3432](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3432).

`updateSbtClassifiers` does not use the correct resolvers. Add the following to your `build.sbt` file:

```
updateSbtClassifiers / dependencyResolution := IvyDependencyResolution((updateSbtClassifiers / ivyConfiguration).value)
```

**Sources not attaching**

Even if the `updateSbtClassifiers` successfully downloads and resolves the `src` and `doc` IDEA may not attach them.

This seems to be a bug in the [sbt-structure plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/sbt-structure). See [SCL-13619](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13619) for details.

**No attempt at downloading**

If for some reason this doesn't download the sources (there is no failed download message) then have a look in your `.ivy2/exclude_classifiers` file. I'm not entirely sure what this file is for but I do know that sbt will exclude anything that is in here.

In my case it had a whole lot of things that I didn't want excluded so I deleted it and then it worked. Delete at your own risk.

Comment: thanks! helped me to resolve sources of the [tag:scala.js] plugin.  `updateSbtClaissifiers` did nothing, but the "Longer way" helped.  
Now the question: what does `reload return build run:` mean? The line as it is caues error, `reload return` seems to be enough.

Comment: Woops I think that was a copy/paste error. It should just be `reload return`. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reload plugins` to go into the project that contains the plugins. If you type `libraryDependencies` you can (for example) see the list of plugin dependencies. Use `reload return` to return to your normal sbt console.

More information here: [Commands for managing the build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Commands+for+managing+the+build+definition)